# Folder struct understanding

Tags: ros2, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to understand the folder struct that's created `ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python robot_pkg`.
Here is the folder structure

```
robot_pkg
        ├── package.xml
        ├── resource
        │   └── robot_pkg
        ├── setup.cfg
        ├── setup.py
        ├── test
        │   ├── __pycache__
        │   │   ├── test_copyright.cpython-38-PYTEST.pyc
        │   │   ├── test_flake8.cpython-38-PYTEST.pyc
        │   │   └── test_pep257.cpython-38-PYTEST.pyc
        │   ├── test_copyright.py
        │   ├── test_flake8.py
        │   └── test_pep257.py
        └── robot_pkg
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── mqtt_subscriber.py
            ├── __pycache__
            │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
            └── robot.py
```

I am more interested in `test`, `resource` and `__init__.py`.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399987/folder-struct-understanding/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`resource/robot_pkg` - In order to detect that a package is installed, ROS2 needs to install a marker file. Similar to installing the packages manifest in ROS 1.

You can read more about colcon File System Index Layout there:

https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/blob/master/ament_cmake_core/doc/resource_index.md

`test` - I put there non-ROS-node specific unit tests, use them like there:

https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial.html#run-tests

Source about colcon:

https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/index.html

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0